# How can I stick a fixed(sticky) sidebar to my content section on a centered div layout?

Tags: layout, html

I understand sticking a sidebar or navigation against the edge of a website with this code

```
position: fixed;
height: 132px;
left: 0;
top: 185px;
width: 24px;
```

but I would like to stick a bar to the main portion of my layout, to the grey content section at my website [here](http://pixphoriad.haneuri.net) so that it scrolls the way the code I showed above would have a sidebar scroll, but will stay stuck to the centered content no matter how big the resolution a viewer has is, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That grey area seems to be not a part of your HTML, seems like just a background image, is that so? Can you provide the structure of your HTML mainly the display area in the center and the grey area. How are they separated? You may need to use javascript and/or jquery to place your sidebar or may be just simple css. Not easy to tell the best way without knowing the HTML structure.

Comment: It's the background image for the content section. I figure it is css, if you can stick a sidebar to the left edge of a page, or a right, then it's probably the same for sticking one against a content section. But the code I posted above needs exact positioning, which doesn't allow for a layout that centers no matter resolution. I think. I'm not sure.
My layout is divs with css styling. Very simple-- are you unable to view full page source?
Either way-- I'm looking for a css solution if at all possible. I love working with css.

Comment: This code sets up the content section, and the navigation is below the content (located in my footer php file). From what I know of CSS, I'm pretty sure that I'm gonna have to stick the sidebar to the wrapper/content area

     <div id="wrapper">

 <div id="header"></div><!-- #header-->

 <div id="middle">

       <div id="container">
        <div id="content">

Comment: Hi Kristin, I checked out your source. Try taking your sidebar div out of the "wrapper" div which has a 950px fixed width, then apply ".sidebar" class to your sidebar div. p.s. I haven't seen any ".sidebar" class in your page or in your style.css file. Have I missed it?

Comment: I haven't tried to place it yet so there isn't a sidebar class yet. And I'm not wanting my navigation on the left to be the sidebar (though that is a good idea). But it would make sense to take it out of the wrapper.
The little facebook/tweet sidebar next to the content section on this website (http://kisuki.net/) is what I'm going for. Except not with the facebook stuff-- it'd have my counter and some other links on it. I'm looking for the css code that would stick it there.

Comment: Actually, I think I got it :p wanna check it real fast to see if it's doin okay?